# No XFCE Animated Resource Monitor available

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, xfce, debian-buster

I am running the latest version of kali (Debian Based OS) with XFCE on my laptop (not VM), please see further info below.

When using a VM version for work I am able to see an animated CPU usage in the taskbar.

For the life of me, I can't get it to work on my local device (I get lag spikes so I am trying to track that).

Any idea on how I get this installed/working on my device natively?

(Tried to post a pic, but I don't have enough reputation on this platform).

```
xfce4-panel 4.16.3 (Xfce 4.16)
```

`uname -a Linux Laptop 5.15.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.15.5-2kali2 (2021-12-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2022.1
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

Comment: I can see the CPU animated on my Kali 2022.1 VM as well. Kernel 5.14. XFCE 4.16.  Did you add properly on your real machine?  Right click within the icon area, Panel, Add new Item?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So there are a few options in the panel menu, I have gone through and there is an animated monitor, so thank you.   However, it is an orange and green one and smaller than the kali VM version.   I can't post a picture yet unfortunately.

Comment: My Icon is orange and green and as tall as the panel bar so it cannot be any bigger

Comment: Oh! That's odd my VM is blue.   Issue closed!